# Expression Engine doesn't save changes when I click the Submit/Update button

Tags: ee2

Fairly regularly, when in the admin panel editing a template, creating post content, or even creating a channel entry - when I click the Update or Submit button it takes me to the admin panel home page and none of my changes have been saved. This happens several times a day. I have 3 different EE installs that I've tried from several computers and have the same problem on all three. One of the EE installs is completely vanilla with zero add-ons.

As a new EE user, I am really liking it except for when this happens because it eats up my time tremendously. Has anyone in the EE community had an issue like this before, or better yet have a solution?  Thanks!

Comment: This is already on the Bug Tracker of [Expressionengine](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19920#12394).

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I couldn't get to the bug tracker without signing up and paying for a support plan. Any work arounds available or time frame for fixing that they mention?

Comment: You don't need a support plan for accessing the bug tracker. There's a really big discussion there. For now, turn off the secure forms.

Answer (score 0):

What version of EE is installed.  I used to have the same issue on 2.7.2, but recently upgraded to 2.7.3 and haven't had the issue since *knock on wood*

Comment: Currently on 2.7.3.